# .obj Texture and Color Not Showing in Three.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

For some reason when I add a new model in .obj and .mtl into my three.js code, the color will become white, despite whatever the original color or texture is. The following is a snippet of the code responsible for the pig model:

```js
// pigmodel
            var objLoader = new OBJLoader();
            var mtlLoader = new MTLLoader();
            function loadpigmodel( x, y, z, ang, scale ) {

                mtlLoader.setPath( './images/' );
                mtlLoader.load( 'Pig1.mtl', function ( loadedMesh ) {

                    objLoader.setMaterials( loadedMesh );
                    objLoader.load( './images/Pig1.obj', function ( object ) {

                        switch ( scale ) {

                            case 'big':
                                object.scale.set( 100, 100, 100 );
                                break;
                            case 'small':
                                object.scale.set( 90, 90, 90 );
                                break;
                            default:

                        }
```

The code above simulates a pigsty with some compost boxes. As you can see, the pig displayed in the code is white, even though it should be pink. The fence should also have wooden texture, but instead, it is also white.[pig model image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGsmo.png)

We suspect that there is something wrong with the mtl file of the things that became white. The full code and the mtl files are included in this [hyperlink](https://github.com/Junle-C/Pigsty-Three.js/releases/tag/v1.0.0).

Answer (score 0):

in `Pig1.obj` you have `usemtl Pig1` (use material Pig1) which assumes there is a decleration `newmtl Pig1` (new material Pig1) somewhere in `Pig1.mtl`, but when you check that file, there is no such material, only `newmtl pigskin`

Solution:

- Open `Pig1.mtl`
- Change `newmtl pigskin` to `newmtl Pig1`

Or change the usemtl to pigskin in your obj-file, whichever makes you happier.

Comment: For some reason after I changed it, the pig are still white. However, the .mtl file for the compost boxes works just fine.

Comment: Stop abusing the java-3d tag please.